# Why is this custom email template button not working?

Tags: custom-button

Need a little help with a custom button directing User to a custom email template. My Leads button works like a champ but the same button in Contacts refuses to play nicely:

This (Leads) button works just fine:

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Lead.Id}&p2_lkid={!Lead.Name}&template_id=00X40000001zFGm');
```

... but ...

This (Contacts) button is essentially the same but throws an error no matter what changes I make to it:

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Contact.Id}&p2_lkid={!Contact.Name}&template_id=00X40000001zFGm');
```

the error thrown is :

> URL No Longer Exists

Am I missing something obvious here? Where should I be looking to resolve this URL error?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your template use merges for Lead fields?

Comment: This is the template:  {!User.Name}
{!User.Title}
ph: {!User.Phone}
{!User.Email}
{!User.Email_Signature_Additional_Info__c}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the p2_lkid should be linked to the contact id and not to the contact name.

Please try: `location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Contact.Id}&p2_lkid={!Contact.Id}&template_id=00X40000001zFGm');`

See: http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/